# Xamarin Live Player not showing up

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

Hi I am trying the Xamarin Live Player for Xamarin cross platform app development.

I did the following:

1) I have installed the Xamarin Live Player on my iphone from App Store

On Windows PC, I have downloaded and Installed VS2017 Community and created a small testing app

2) On Visual Studio 2017 Community, I installed the Xamarin Updater.

Problem:
I dont see any Live Player to choose in VS2017 Community.

for above item (2)
Visual Studio 2017 community is not the Same as Visual Studio 2017 Preview??
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/install/

Is it ok to download it on the same PC?

Please advise the instruction to follows.

**Update**

I have installed VS2017 Preview and selected Mobile Development with .Net (I think this is xamarin cross platform )

I have downloaede the sample app:
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/LivePlayer/ColorControl/

And I still dont see the Xamarin Live player

**Update**

Finally, the Xamarin Live Player show up.

This is what I did:

a) After installing VS2017 Preview, 
launch the VS2017 Preview, got Tools> Extensions and Update

a1) Download all the Updates:
    Xamarin for visual Studio,
    XamarinApple SDK, 
    Xamarin Android SDK,
    Mono Debugging for Visual Studio

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have the preview of VS 2017 15.3 and go to the Alpha channel in Xamarin.

Comment: I m at lost.  I hv installed and opened VS2017 Preview on Win10 PC. 1) Have paired the PC with iphone using Bluetooth. 2) Have turn on the Xamarin live player.  I dont see the Selection for Live Player and I dont understand what is Alpha channel in Xamarin.  Would Appreciate if you can show me the Steps.  It is so confusion at this stage. please help.

Comment: is this Xamarin Live Player only for Mac ?? like install VS2017 Preview on Mac.

Comment: You can use it on Windows. That was its big selling point. Run an iOS app without a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If Xamarin Live Player is still not showing up in the Device selection list after following @MilkBottle steps, you may need to go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other - and select "Enable Xamarin Live Player".

Comment: When navigating down Tools > Options > Xamarin, I do not have the "Other" option enabled.  I see "Android Setting" and "iOS Setting" but not "Other".  I've got VS 2017 installed along with Xamarin, as well as the newest updates for both.  Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You need to download VS 2017 preview to use Xamarin live player.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know that that the preview edition was a separate download.  Once I grabbed that from Microsoft I was able to find the correct options.